# React Native import json file & read the content

Tags: json, react-native

I tried to load an .json file and read the content. But all I get is an output like this:

[image: AlertWindow]

this is my Code:

```
 import movies from './movies.json';

  /* 
  ... 
  */

  function componentWillMount() {
    return (
      fetch(movies).then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => 
      {this.setState({hugeText: data.something});
      })
    );
  }
  function searchForName(){
     var content = componentWillMount();
     alert(content);
  }
```

It would like to get the real content as a String.

Comment: please share the full code

Comment: what is displaying in the alert?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use componentWillMount like that...

```
componentWillMount() {
  fetch(movies).then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => { 
    this.setState({hugeText: data.something});
  });
}

searchForName() {
  alert(this.state.hugeText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `ComponentWillMount`:

From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount):

> UNSAFE_componentWillMount() is invoked just before mounting occurs. It
>   is called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously
>   in this method will not trigger an extra rendering. Generally, we
>   recommend using the constructor() instead for initializing state.
>
> Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.
>   For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.

Now, set a state variable in your component, to save the value that you will receive from that API call:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = { hugeText: '' }
}
```

If you just want to render what the object is as a string, use:

```
JSON.stringify(your_object_here)
```

Use it like this:

```
function componentDidMount() {
  fetch(movies).then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({hugeText: JSON.stringify( data.something ) } , () => {
        alert(this.state.hugeText); // This will happen AFTER the state has been set
      });
    })
}
```

You can use `this.state.hugeText` afterwards in your render function for example.

Have a read at [the setState API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) as well.